# Parsing specific array from external file not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, external

i am trying to parse array '**browser-side**' from external json file, but its not working.

need help

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Parsing specific array from external file</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

$.getJSON('http://www.mybeautiful.net63.net/test/myTutorials-json.js', function(data) {

   obj = JSON.parse(data);
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.browser-side.length; i++)
    {
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += obj.browser-side[i].display + " " + obj.browser-side[i].url + ",";
    }
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's not working? What results do you get? What have you tried so far?

Comment: i am trying to get result from [this external](http://www.mybeautiful.net63.net/test/myTutorials-json.js) file. I get no result. check the above code.